# What does SQLiteDatabase.query(...) returns if no record in the database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

From Android **documentation**:

> Returns
>
> A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry. Note that
>   Cursors are not synchronized, see the documentation for more details.

What if my table has ZERO records?

Does it return null. Or does it return an empty Cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty cursor. You can use `getCount()` to confirm if the `Cursor` is empty or check if `moveToFirst()` returns false (i.e., it could not move to the first row).